# Symfony 2 Static asset authorisations (.js behind firewall)

Tags: security, symfony, authorization, assetic

What is the procedure for securing static assets (javascript and css) behind the firewall?
I have an admin section which uses javascript heavily. I don't really want to expose the code to the public.

I currently compile all my javascript using assetic to files in /web/admin/js/xyz.js

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to put static files under Security. Looking forward for answers to this question!

Comment: What web server are you using? You could use that to secure the requests by IP or Cookie.

Comment: Apache. I don't want to go down that route (It's not practical), I'd like to use the built in symfony firewall.

Comment: Another example use case is my current one. I have a Javascript SPA that utilises several APIs to build a business critical dashboard. I don't want anyone except those who are authorised to access the SPA. Yes an admin could login, steal the dashboard source code and make a copy of it, but then the same admin could just steal server side code anyway. If someone's a thief authenticating them against your database doesn't stop them being a thief.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a controller to serve the static file and secure that controller. Something like:

```
/** 
 * Serves static javascript file. 
 * We have configured /secure to be secured by some firewall
 *
 * @Route("/secure/xyz.js", name="static_xyz")
 */
public function staticXyzAction()
{   

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/javascript',
    );  

    return new Response(file_get_contents($this->get('kernel')
        ->getRootDir().'../web/admin/js/xyz.js'), 200, $headers);
}
```

This is just an example with the data you provided. Obviously in your final code the file being served should be located in some directory which is not directly accesible by the web server.

The obvious downside to this approach is performance. PHP is much slower for serving an static file than your web server but depending on your load this may not be an issue.

Comment: Could you please make font bolder, where is says that `the file being served should be located in some directory which is not directly accesible by the web server`?

Comment: Backend load is light so this would work ok I think. I guess that If I want to employ the firewall then I have no option but to load the full framework. Thanks

Comment: @thecatontheflat I'm not sure how practical this will be within the confines of assetic (which complies to directories within the web root). Can't I just force any requests to any static assets within the /adminassets location to pass through the front controller and make sure that any secure assets are always compiled to that folder?

Comment: I guess you can, but it should be changed in your web-server configuration. I am sure that is contains directive "if file does not exist then pass request to `app.dev`" ;)

Comment: You can implement a scrip that dumps the assetic files, then moves them to another location

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to "hide" these admin js files? The js should not perform critical auth or check rights, but just converse with your Sf2 Apis / Controllers which do that, and should not be critical if read. This is a conception matter.

If you are afraid that a lambda user / hacker sees these js files, you could set a very complicated random js output in Assetic. The Symfony .htaccess allows user to access static files only if they know their exact url, they cannot list your repository where you store your builded assets, the firewall catch that.

And last security mesure, use yui-minifier with Assetic to minify and obfusacate your builded js files.

Comment: They don't contain any critical auth or check rights. But it's my proprietary application code - and as such I don't want to leave it somewhere it can be downloaded. Your approach would work (practically) but it's kinda like security by obscurity (even though its not a security risk per se. but a business risk). Obfuscated code can be reverse engineered. Thanks for the comment though - you've offered a practical solution to my problem (if it is a problem at all).

Comment: I also agree it's a bit overkill and probably useless. 1. Who wants to steal JavaScript code ? Especially obfuscated. If it's not designed as a proper library, for a very general purpose, I'd find it easier to write it myself, and if it is you should open source it :-) 2. Those who want to steal it would need the URL to get it anyways, which they won't if they don't have access to the admin section (Assetic makes  file names hard to guess). 3. They can still get it, if an admin sends it to them. Client side language are given to the clients.

Comment: The responses should not be directed towards whether or not the files should be secured, for whatever reason, the developer may want to hide files from external users. The answers should be directed towards helping find a solution to that problem. I find the responses minimally helpful based on the question asked.